# What is the reason for the error "Failed to decode JSON" in MediaWiki::API?

Tags: perl, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

We have private MediaWiki installation inside our company. Based on daily builds on our source code, we update the wiki with Perforce labels so that people can use the build that is labeled for streamlined process. We tried to automate this using Perl scripts on a Windows server using [MediaWiki::Bot](http://p3rl.org/MediaWiki%3a%3aBot) and [MediaWiki::API](http://p3rl.org/MediaWiki%3a%3aAPI).

```
use MediaWiki::Bot;
use MediaWiki::API;

my $mw = MediaWiki::API->new();
$mw->{config}->{api_url} = 'http://somewiki/w/index.php/title#feature_List';

# log in to the wiki
$mw->login({
        lgname     => 'username',
        lgpassword => 'password'
          || die $mw->{error}->{code} . ': ' . $mw->{error}->{details};

          # get a list of articles in category
          my $articles = $mw->list({
                action  => 'query',
                list    => 'categorymembers',
                cmtitle => 'Category:Perl',
                cmlimit => 'max'
            }) || die $mw->{error}->{code} . ': ' . $mw->{error}->{details};

          # and print the article titles
          foreach (@{$articles}) {
            print "$_->{title}\n";
        }
```

Output:

```
2: Failed to decode JSON returned by http://vaporwiki/w/index.php/Executor#Execu
tor_Feature_List
Decoding Error:
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at charact
er offset 0 (before "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLI...") at C:/Perl/lib/MediaWiki/API.pm l
ine 398

Returned Data: <whole page data>
```

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose your installation problem because you neglected to reveal any relevant information, not even your Perl distro (ActiveState Perl?). - Because Stack Overflow works best when there is only one topic per question, I have deleted that part of the question, it is still available from [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11217610/revisions). Copy this text and [open a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), so that it can taken care of properly.

Answer (score 5):

The [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) URL is wrong. Try `http://vaporwiki/w/api.php`.

Comment: but the link in our local wiki looks like
http://intranet/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: That's the user interface for MediaWiki, but as daxim says, for API access you have to use the API address instead.